# How can I change the background color of multiple elements at once using an onclick event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below is my current code. It will create a grid of squares that change to a random color when you mouseover. I am trying to make an event listener for a click on the first square, and when it is clicked it resets all the squares in the grid back to the original color. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, I am pretty new to Javascript, but I believe it could have something to do with my syntax in the resetAllSquares function.

```js
"use strict";

let squares = document.querySelectorAll('div');

/*Mouseover change to random color*/
squares.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
    changeColor(item);
}))

const changeColor = (item) => {
    item.style.background = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

/* Reset current square */
squares.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    resetSquare(item);
}))

const resetSquare = (item) => {
    item.style.background = "#737373";
}

/* Reset all squares */
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', () => {
    resetAllSquares();
})

const resetAllSquares = () => {
    squares.style.background = "#737373";
}
```

```css
.square {
    background-color: #737373;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="first"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```

Comment: Clicking on the first square produces a `TypeError: squares.style is undefined` error message on the console. Always good to check for errors first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `squares` is still an array that you've been looping over to change the color in the other instances, you need to loop over `squares` again to change them back.

```
const resetAllSquares = () => {
    squares.forEach(item => item.style.background = "#737373";)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop through the squares to set their background :

```
squares.forEach(square => { square.style.background = "#737373" });
```

```js
let squares = document.querySelectorAll('div');

/*Mouseover change to random color*/
squares.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
  changeColor(item);
}))

const changeColor = (item) => {
  item.style.background = "#" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16);
}

/* Reset current square */
squares.forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  resetSquare(item);
}))

const resetSquare = (item) => {
  item.style.background = "#737373";
}

/* Reset all squares */
document.getElementById('first').addEventListener('click', () => {
  resetAllSquares();
})

const resetAllSquares = () => {
  squares.forEach(square => { square.style.background = "#737373" });
}
```

```css
.square {
  background-color: #737373;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  margin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" id="first"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
<div class="square"></div>
```